# get the href link after traversing through divs using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to Selenium.. I am trying to get the href link which is present inside two div elements

```
<div class="abc def">
     <div class="foo xyz">
          <a href="/watch123" ></a>
     </div>
</div>
```

How do I get the href link? I have tried

```
persons = []
for person in item.find_elements_by_class_name('abc.def'):
    title = person.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="foo.xyz"]/a').text
    link = title.get_attribute("href")
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:
assuming your browser driver is called "driver" and all your elements' attributes are unique.

- Xpath:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='foo xyz']/a")
  link = element.get_attribute("href")
  ```
- Css selector:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='foo xyz']>a")
  link = element.get_attribute("href")
  ```