# Selenium: get_attribute returns None

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, html-parsing

I would like to **scrape** all links which are inside the `<div>` tags from some web-page. For example, the piece of HTML-code looks like this:

```
<div class="item_text">         
        <a href="https://perm.aif.ru/culture/details/edinstvennyy_v_rossii_v_solikamske_otkrylsya_novyy_korporativnyy_muzey">
                        <h3>Единственный в России. В Соликамске открылся новый корпоративный музей</h3>
        </a>
    </div>
```

And I would like to get the link: `https://perm.aif.ru/culture/details/edinstvennyy_v_rossii_v_solikamske_otkrylsya_novyy_korporativnyy_muzey`

So I wrote this code using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212473/get-the-href-link-after-traversing-through-divs-using-selenium-in-python) question and answer:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
link = "https://perm.aif.ru/"
driver.get(link)

elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("item_text")
links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elems]

print(links)
```

But it returned me this:

```
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

That is not I have expected to see. How can I fix it? Why does this code return list on None`s?

I use this:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Python 3.8.5
- Selenium 3.141.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links are contained inside `a` elements that are inside `div` elements with class name `item_text`, not inside these `divs` directly.
You can do this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
link = "https://perm.aif.ru/"
driver.get(link)

time.sleep(10)
elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".item_text a")
links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elems]

print(links)
```

I also added a sleep to ensure the page is loaded before we getting the links

Comment: Just for my understanding all this css selectors stuff. For example, what if there will be one more tag? Not the `<div class="super_div"><a href="link">Wow link</a></div>` but the `<div class="super_div"><h2><a href="link">Wow link</a><h2></div>`. Will the css selector be something like this `.super_div h2 a`?

Comment: Both will be correct. My locator says "element with class name item_text, inside it some element with tag name a" while your expression says "element with class name super, inside it element with h2 tag name, inside it element with tag name a"